# Xcode swift tests not discovered

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I'm using Xcode 9 and I'm trying to write unit tests following the Apple iOS tutorial [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/DefineYourDataModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH20-SW1).

Problem is that my unit tests aren't being discovered, only the stub in another test project in the same solution.

[image: Test code]

The test in the screenshot should fail, but it doesn't as it's not discovered.

The `testExample` method is shown below

[image]

As you can see it has the little diamond indicating it has a test, but not next to the one I've created. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was to prefix the function name with `test`

So the function now looks like
[image: valid test function name]

And the test is now discovered in the test explorer
[image: Test explorer]